# php echo variable1, pause and echo variable 2 then echo the rest of variable1

Tags: php, database, variables, echo

let's say that i have this simplyfied code:

```
$sql = dbquery("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE views > 4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10 ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $url = $row["url"];
  $title = $row["title"];
  $list ='<div><a href="'.$url.'" >'.$title.'</a></div>';
  $ad ='<div>something here</div>';
}

echo $list;
```

instead to display a list of 10 divs, i want to echo 5 divs from `$list`, echo `$ad` then echo the rest of the `$list`

How can i do this?

Later edit :

First problem solved thanks to Michael.

Now, i have a problem with my template, and i don't know how can i add to every X number of $list divs, class="nomar"?

Comment: Just a note - you want to be using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` since you have referenced your columns by key with `$row['url']`, etc.

Comment: thank you, i will replace it.

Comment: i've added a little problem that i still have.

Comment: According to michael's code; $list ='<div class="div_' . $i . '"><a href="'.$url.'" >'.$title.'</a></div>'; After naming divs class is div_1, div_2...

Comment: thank you, this will do it, but i have to add css for div_4, div_8, div_12 and so on... can't i add the class only to every 4 divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter `$i`

```
$sql = dbquery("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE views > 4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10 ");

$i = 1;

// Use mysql_fetch_assoc() rather than mysql_fetch_array()!
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $url = $row["url"];
  $title = $row["title"];

  // Change the list class on a certain number...
  if ($i == 3) {
     $list_class = "normal";
  }
  else $list_class = "some-other-class";
  // Incorporate the new class
  $list ='<div class="' . $list_class . '"><a href="'.$url.'" >'.$title.'</a></div>';

  // Output $list
  echo $list;    

  // Increment your counter
  $i++;

  // Output $ad when you reach 5
  // This only happens once. Afterward, $list continues to print.
  if ($i == 5) {
    $ad ='<div>something here</div>';
    echo $ad;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you again, the only thing is that i replaced $i == 5 with to $i == 6 to display the first 5 ones.

Comment: i still have a problem from my template now: how can i add at every X number displayed $list divs, class="nomar" ?